# How to view queries executed internally from dbeaver

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

When trying to DELETE, INSERT or UPDATE one more table rows inside Table editor (or by using the add, duplicate and delete buttons), i know that dbeaver executes some queries.

Is there a way to view these queries?

I tried the "query manager" button but it doesn't show them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My question might be a duplicate because it was fairly simple to find it.
For anyone that doesn't know how to do it (although there are explicit directions how to do it in the documentation under the topic "Query Manager")
(Yup i didn't knew):

1. Go to "Window" in options bar
2. Click "Preferences"
3. Go to "Database"->"Query Manager"
4. Finally under "Query Types" check the option "Utility functions" and press "Apply"

Edit 28/03/2023:

**For versions 21.3.4 onwards**
See [loakesh bachhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6356958/loakesh-bachhu) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72062721/5510189)

Comment: At least as of version 21.3.5.202202200327, the "Utility functions" setting is now under Preferences: User Interface: Query Manager: Query Types.

Answer (score 9):

To use the Utility function in DBeaver after 21.3.4 onwards you can find it here as below.
[image]